# UICollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths: raising error

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I know there are all sorts of questions related to this, but none of the answers answered this.

Anyways, I have a UICollectionView that should be scroll forever, but I can't seem to get `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` to work. It raises the error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:3688
```

Here is my code:

```
#import "ImageSliderViewController.h"

#define ITEM_CELL_IDENTIFIER @"ItemCell"

@interface ImageSliderViewController ()

@end

@implementation ImageSliderViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupCollectionView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionView methods

-(void)setupCollectionView {
    self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    loadingGap = 5;

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[ImageSliderCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:ITEM_CELL_IDENTIFIER];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    [self loadMorePosts];
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ImageSliderCell *cell = (ImageSliderCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ITEM_CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.item];

    NSLog(@"%d : %d",indexPath.item,self.items.count-1);

    if (indexPath.item >= self.items.count-1) {
        [self loadMorePosts];
    }

    return cell;

}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = self.collectionView.frame.size;
    size.height = size.height/2;
    return size;
}

- (void)loadMorePosts
{
    NSLog(@"Loading new items");
    NSUInteger loopTill = self.items.count + loadingGap;
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToLoad = [NSMutableArray new];
    while (self.items.count < loopTill) {
        [indexPathsToLoad addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count inSection:0]];

        NSLog(@"Added section %d",self.items.count);

        AsyncImageView *img = [[DatabaseFetcher alloc] getPostWithID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)self.items.count]
                                                       inSection:@"features"
                                                       withFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height)];
        [self.items addObject:@[img]];
    };
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToLoad];
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I updated the code to use `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` and some other improvements base on suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Update your question with the rest of the error.

Comment: @maddy - That's _all_ it gives me. Thanks!

Comment: The log should give you a lot more detail about the assertion error.

Comment: @maddy - It doesn't that's all it gives me. I wish I had a bit more info on it, since I'm completely stumped.

Comment: If you get this error while debugging in Xcode, the Xcode console will definitely show more details about the cause of the assertion.

Comment: @maddy - The console app nor the output is giving me anything else. :/

Comment: Where are you using `-insertItemsAtIndexPaths`? Please don't edit questions to fix the error you describe.

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count inSection:0]
```

Should be:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0]
```

**update**

And you should submit all of your insertions at once by building up an `NSMutableArray` of index paths in your loop and inserting them at the end (as you've done and commented out). Alternatively, you can put your loop inset of a `performBatchUpdates` block.

Comment: Updated my answer. You've got two issues, the second being that you can't call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` multiple times outside of a batch update block.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the answers.

It looks like I had a miscalculation when trying one of the solutions on the other thread. Here's my new solution that works:

```
-(void)addNewItems
{
    NSLog(@"Loading new items");
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToLoad = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < LOADING_GAP; i++) {
        [indexPathsToLoad addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.items.count inSection:0]];
        [self.items addObject:@"Test"];
    }
    if (self.items.count == LOADING_GAP) {
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } else {
        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToLoad];
    }
}
```

Thank you!